# Why can't I list Node.prototype's properties?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var props = {}

for (var prop in Node.prototype) {
    if (Node.prototype.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        props[prop] = Node.prototype[prop];
    }
}
```

I'm using this code to try to get all properties of the `Node.prototype` object but it says "Illegal invocation" on this line: `props[prop] = Node.prototype[prop];`. What am I missing?

Comment: Some property getters of `Node.prototype` require a proper object as context, and throw otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access a getter (maybe `innerHTML` or something like this) on the prototype, but it can only be accessed on an instance of a node. You can skip getters with this:

```
 if(!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype, prop).get) {
   props[prop] = Node.prototype[prop];
 }
```